# Nvidia Drivers, Repo v.s Website

Tags: 12.10, drivers, nvidia

I know the way to install both, I managed to get both working as it should, now im asking, Which is better ? as for your experience is there a different between Nvidia-Experimental-310 from Repo and the Binary installation from Nvidia Website ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in actual performance, but from a package managing point of view the repositories are best. That way the package you install is registered with `apt` (the package manager) which allows easy updating and removal, and takes care of dependencies. Installing from a `.run` file (nvidia website) does not have these advantages; removing it might not be trivial.

NOT RECOMMENDED:

You can convert the `.run` file to a `.deb` (the file format `apt` works with) by following the steps in [How can I convert the Nvidia driver installer into a deb?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130662/how-can-i-convert-the-nvidia-driver-installer-into-a-deb).
That is also how the driver gets into the repository in the first place. You would for instance do this if there is a new driver on the nvidia website which is not yet in the repositories, and you can't wait.