# No nVidia/nouveau modules loaded, but sytem working fine?

Tags: nvidia, 13.04, bumblebee, nouveau

Okay, so right now, I have installed both nvidia drivers and bumblebee and am getting all the necessary functions working - battery conservation, higher fps etc....

But when I try
     `lsmod | grep nvidia*`
or
     `lsmod | grep nouveau`
or
     `lsmod | grep bumblebee`

I am not getting any working modules of these types.

Is something missing, because my synaptics shows the drivers installed and am pretty much sure the system is working fine. Also would an kernel upgrade break my system? Or is there someway to do it without breaking it?

Hey guys, is this even possible?

Comment: Any help on this would be appreciated as I would be updating the kernel soon, and would like to know whats where in the sytem before attempting that

Comment: I use bumblebee to, but lsmod | grep nouveau works for me. I have noticed in the other post that you have instaled nvidia drivers then bumblebee. I don't do it like that. I just install bumblebee witch isntals some nvidia drivers from their repository sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia

Comment: @Rat2000 thanks!..unfortunately from many nvidia drivers I tried, 319 is the only one that worked for me.. hence using them.

Answer (score 1):

I [haven't managed to get to run bumblebee yet](https://askubuntu.com/q/301919/30266), but I'm also seeing no `nouveau` entries in the output of `dmesg` until trying to run something that actually accesses the discrete graphics adapter with `optirun`:

```
optirun glxgears
```

Then you should be getting `nouveau` or `nvidia` entries in your logs, and also in the output of `lsmod`.

By default, only the integrated graphics adapter is used, most probably with a different driver.

Comment: Hey you are right! running something with optirun did make the nvidia module visible. But no bumblebee. Does that mean that optimus technology is not being used in my system?

Comment: @charlie: Try `ps -elf | grep bumblebeed`, you should see two entries -- one for the grep, the other for the Bumblebee daemon.

Comment: Yes I do get two lines. What do they mean? What does the command do?

Comment: @charlie: `ps -elf` lists pretty much all processes, I don't remember exactly what the individual switches mean, but you can ask `man ps`. `grep` searches in this list and returns the matching lines, which will of course also include the `grep` process itself. The pipe `|` asks the `grep` process to use the output of the `ps` process as its input.